# Отследить нажатие CTRL в Qt

Tags: qt

Как отследить нажатие на CTRL? 
Так:

```
if (event->key()== Qt::CTRL)
    qDebug() << "CTRL";
```

или так:

```
if (event->key() == Qt::ControlModifier)
    qDebug() << "CTRL";
```

не получается

Comment: А так `if(event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)`?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin работает